# Not able to move item using absolute position's values?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to move my `hamburger icon` which has a `position: absolute` using the values `top: 20 left: 20` etc. I have placed the icon just after the `body` tag and have given the `body` tag a `position: relative`. Why am I not able to adjust the hamburger icon's positioning?

**JSFiddle demo** (You may need to resize you broswer down to a smaller size to view the hamburger icon: http://jsfiddle.net/nqLtvmd3/5/

HTML:

```
<body>
<div class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger mobile-nav-icon"></div>
    <div class="container-fluid">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="nice-blue-bg">
                    <div class="container">

                            <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4">
                                        <div class="logo">
                                            TESTING                                     
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">
                                                <nav class="main-nav">
                                                    <ul>
                                                        <li class="">
                                                            <a href="#">Home</a>
                                                            <a href="#">About Me</a>
                                                            <a href="#">Latest Work</a>
                                                            <a href="#">Contact Me</a>
                                                        </li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                </nav>
                                            </div>
                                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                            </div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
    background: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}

a:hover, a:focus { 
    text-decoration:  none;
    color: yellow;
}
/* Fix firefox issue with images not resizing whilst using bootstrap class */
.img-responsive {
    width: 100%;
}

.nice-blue-bg {

    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(145deg, #134E5E 10%, #71B280 90%); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
    background:    -moz-linear-gradient(145deg, #134E5E 10%, #71B280 90%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background:     -ms-linear-gradient(145deg, #134E5E 10%, #71B280 90%); /* IE10 */
    background:      -o-linear-gradient(145deg, #134E5E 10%, #71B280 90%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background:         linear-gradient(145deg, #134E5E 10%, #71B280 90%); /* W3C */
    width: 100%;
    height: 620px;
}


.logo {
    font-family: Lato;
    color: white;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-weight: 100;
    margin-top: 80px;
}

.main-nav {
    margin-top: 90px;
}

.main-nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.main-nav li, .main-nav a {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 30px;
    float: right;
}

.main-nav a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #eaeaea;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: uppercase;

}

.main-nav a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}



.mobile-nav-icon {
    display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) { 

    /* This is the hamburger icon I want to be able to move */
    .mobile-nav-icon {
        z-index: 1;
        position: absolute;
        top: 20;
        left: 0;
        display: block;
        color: white;
        font-size: 30px;
        cursor: pointer;

    }

    .logo {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .main-nav {
        margin-top: 20px;
        display: none;
    }

    .main-nav li {
        float: none;
        text-align: center;
        display: block;
    }

    .welcome {
        text-align: center;
    }

    .main-nav li, .main-nav a {
        margin-left: 0;
        display: block;
        float: none;
    }

    .main-nav a {
        padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
        border-top: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
        margin-left: -15px;
        margin-right: -15px;
    }

    .main-nav a:last-child {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #c2c2c2;
        margin-left: -15px;
        margin-right: -15px;
    }


    .nice-blue-bg {
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        padding-bottom: 30px;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify units:

```
.mobile-nav-icon {
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px; /* Use PX units */
    left: 0;
    display: block;
    color: white;
    font-size: 30px;
    cursor: pointer;

}
```

Comment: It happens to us all.